# The installation of SQL server agent is disabled on full edition of sql server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

Practically overnight, the SQL Server agent that had been working for over a year failed on a server running SQL Server 2008 R2. When attempting to restart it, it fails immediately with the message

> "This installation of SQL Server Agent is disabled.  The edition of SQL Server that installed this service does not support SQL Server Agent."

But it is a full edition, and as I've said, its been working fine for over a year. Perhaps on a related note, the same day the Agent first failed, we also started seeing:

> "License Activation (slui.exe) failed with the following error code:
>   hr=0x80072EE7"

I know slui is a windows activation related service, could it be related to SQL server suddenly thinking it's an express edition?

Comment: What is returned when you run the query "select @@version"?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) - 10.50.6560.0 (X64)   Dec 28 2017 15:03:48   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: SQL Server doesn't just decide to downgrade itself. There's no "full" edition and the version string proves this is an Express instance. Which edition was installed? How did you connect to it? Did you use the `server\SQLEXPRESS` instance name? How did you connect now?

Comment: Are you connecting to the server directly, or are there any DNS or SQL Server aliases involved?

Comment: We are connecting to the server directly, and no the instance is named. Also im not sure which edition was installed as we did not handle the instalation, just the setup of dbs and jobs. Which worked until they didnt as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out, I received bad information from the server admin, and the installation is in fact an express edition. The admin just assumed it was the agent that stopped working, since the backups started failing. Turns out it was in fact not the agent. Thanks everyone for all the input.

Answer (score 2):

The first place I would start is the SQL Server Error Log. What does it say?

Your `@@Version` stated it was Express. I doubt that is incorrect. By default, database mail, SQL Server Agent, and many other features aren't able to be installed or enabled easier in [SQL Server Express Editions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017). This is why it's *Free*.

Some people have shown how to get around *some* of these limitations, especially [database mail.](https://www.veryiz.com/2017/configure-sql-database-email/) Perhaps someone did something similar for SQL Agent, and now Microsoft has figured it out. Or, someone downgraded your server.

You can check the installation date by running the following snippet [provided by Pinal](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/05/sql-server-retrieve-sql-server-installation-date-time/)

```
SELECT create_date
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE sid = 0x010100000000000512000000
```

Note, there is no *Full edition*. There are:

- Datacenter
- Enterprise
- Standard
- Web
- Workgroup
- Express